# Performing calculations on subset of data frame subset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
user_id   char_id   rating
100          33          3
100          44          2
100          33          1
100          44          4
111          55          5
111          44          4
111          55          5
```

I have a data frame formatted similarly to this one and am trying to perform calculations on the ratings after they have been grouped by `user_id` and `char_id`. 
It doesn't work but I need to do something like `data.groupby('user_id', 'char_id')` and then calculate the moving average for each `char_id` for each `user_id`. Any help? I have several thousand `user_id` so I can't go through and select one at a time for the calculations.

I need to somehow iterate over the `user_id` column and group all the same user_ids together, and save that format so that `user_id`s are separate. Then I need to do the same thing, iterating over `char_id` for each `user_id` subset and saving that format so that I can finally perform calculations on the subsets of subsets of ratings. So far all my attempts have been unsuccessful. The closest I came was:

```py
def divide_by_user(data):
    for user in data['user_id']:
        user_data = data.where(data['user_id'] == user)
        return user_data
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do this manually, creating and summarizing subsets like this is exactly what `DataFrame.groupby()` is for. Create your groupby:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['user_id', 'char_id'])
```

Then you can apply a function to each subset. It sounds like you want either `rolling_mean` or `expanding_mean`, both of which are already available in `pandas`:

```
df['cum_average'] = grouped['rating'].apply(pd.expanding_mean)
# New column now contains the average rating for each subset,
#   including all values that have been seen so far.
df
Out[43]: 
   user_id  char_id  rating  cum_average
0      100       33       3            3
1      100       44       2            2
2      100       33       1            2
3      100       44       4            3
4      111       55       5            5
5      111       44       4            4
6      111       55       5            5
```

---

Using a larger randomly-generated dataset to demonstrate `rolling_window()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [random.choice([100, 111, 112]) for n in range(n_rows)],
    'char_id': [random.choice([33, 44, 55]) for n in range(n_rows)],
    'rating': [random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) for n in range(n_rows)]
})
grouped = df.groupby(['user_id', 'char_id'])
df['cum_average'] = grouped['rating'].apply(pd.rolling_mean, window=7)
# Output. The rolling average will be NaN until enough values have been
#   observed for that subset, you can change this using the
#   min_periods argument to rolling_window
df.sort(columns=['user_id', 'char_id'])
     char_id  rating  user_id  cum_average
3         33       1      100          NaN
19        33       2      100          NaN
22        33       5      100          NaN
34        33       1      100          NaN
47        33       1      100          NaN
48        33       1      100          NaN
49        33       1      100     1.714286
51        33       4      100     2.142857
55        33       2      100     2.142857
60        33       2      100     1.714286
66        33       2      100     1.857143
...
etc.
```

Comment: When I try to execute the code you provided with expanding_mean it runs but the df['cum_average'] just displays a copy of df['rating']. Also, when I try to run with rolling_mean window of 7 (which is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!) I get: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'type.

Comment: @Rachael: Using `rolling_mean` shouldn't be too different, see the new example I've added. I'm not sure what went wrong for you but you may have been putting the `window=7` argument in the wrong place?

Comment: @Rachael: Also, the `expanding_mean` result will just be a copy of the rating column for the first rating in each subset, it's only once you get to the second value in each subset that you'll see the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
"df" is the dataFrame

mean=pd.rolling_mean(df.rating, 7)

Comment: This doesn't seem to deal with the user_id/char_id subsets described in the question?

Comment: Yes, I see your point  you're right, but I do have the same issue with NaN, even if the vector is longer than the window size

Comment: `NaN`s will appear if the `min_periods` argument is greater than 1. So it's not necessarily an issue, it's the expected behaviour of the function and you can change it if you don't like it. You can set `min_periods` to 1 and it will just give you a rolling mean for all values, otherwise it waits until it has seen at least `min_periods` values before it starts calculating the mean.