# How to perform calculations on a subset of a column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With a dataset such as [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
    famid  birth  age   ht
0       1      1  one  2.8
1       1      1  two  3.4
2       1      2  one  2.9
3       1      2  two  3.8
4       1      3  one  2.2
5       1      3  two  2.9
```

...where we've got values for a variable `ht` for different categories of, for example,  `age`  , I would like to adjust a subset of the data in `df['ht']` where `df['age'] == 'one'` *only*. And I would like to do it without creating a new column.

I've tried:

```
df[df['age']=='one']['ht'] = df[df['age']=='one']['ht']*10**6
```

But to my mild surprise the numbers don't change. Maybe because the `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame` warning is triggered in the same run. I've also tried with `df.mask()` and `df.where()`. But to no avail. I'm clearly failing at something very basic here, but I'd really like to know how to do this properly. There are similarly sounding questions such as [Performing calculations on subset of data frame subset in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017807/performing-calculations-on-subset-of-data-frame-subset-in-python), but the suggested solutions here are pointing towards `df.groupby()`, and I don't think this necessarily is the right approach here.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Here's a fully reproducible dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'famid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'birth': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'ht_one': [2.8, 2.9, 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2, 2.3, 2.1],
    'ht_two': [3.4, 3.8, 2.9, 3.2, 2.8, 2.4, 3.3, 3.4, 2.9]
})
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='ht', i=['famid', 'birth'], j='age',
                    sep='_', suffix=r'\w+')
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Comment: @AnoushiravanR My purpose is to learn, and to clear up some apparent misunderstandings of mine with regards to some basic `pandas`. Nothing wrong with your suggestion by the way as far as I can tell. What I *can* tell you is that all the suggested approaches so far *combined* have given me some very valuable new insights. Thank you for taking the time to look at this. And thanks a bunch to all the rest of you. You `pandas` guys are the best!

Comment: As for the warning, `df[df['age']=='one']` creates a new dataframe that may, or may point to the original data structure holding the values of `df`. Or pandas may make a copy of the data. That's mostly harmless when you are only reading values, but obviously bad when writing. You may write to a temporary data structure that is discarded when the operation completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df.loc[df['age'] == 'one', 'ht'] *= 10**6
```

Output:

```
    famid  birth  age         ht
0       1      1  one  2800000.0
1       1      1  two        3.4
2       1      2  one  2900000.0
3       1      2  two        3.8
4       1      3  one  2200000.0
5       1      3  two        2.9
6       2      1  one  2000000.0
7       2      1  two        3.2
8       2      2  one  1800000.0
9       2      2  two        2.8
10      2      3  one  1900000.0
11      2      3  two        2.4
12      3      1  one  2200000.0
13      3      1  two        3.3
14      3      2  one  2300000.0
15      3      2  two        3.4
16      3      3  one  2100000.0
17      3      3  two        2.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
df.assign(ht = df['ht'].mask(df['age'].isin(['one']),df['ht'].mul(10**6)))
```

by using `isin()`, more values from the age column can be added.

Output:

```
    famid  birth  age         ht
0       1      1  one  2800000.0
1       1      1  two        3.4
2       1      2  one  2900000.0
3       1      2  two        3.8
4       1      3  one  2200000.0
5       1      3  two        2.9
6       2      1  one  2000000.0
7       2      1  two        3.2
8       2      2  one  1800000.0
9       2      2  two        2.8
10      2      3  one  1900000.0
11      2      3  two        2.4
12      3      1  one  2200000.0
13      3      1  two        3.3
14      3      2  one  2300000.0
15      3      2  two        3.4
16      3      3  one  2100000.0
17      3      3  two        2.9
```